# Winforms BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a binding source object that fills some textboxes.
In run time, after editing the textboxes I want to be able to retrieve the old values.

how can I retrieve the Textbox's old value and refresh the screen ?
Maybe the binding source has history or something ?!

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. Databinding is not about keeping history. You want the original values, keep them outside of your binding source and controls ;) Basic design principle - to keep the whole databinding infrastructure lean. Because in MANY cases the history is not needed, and in the others it is best implemented in the business side, not the databinding.

Comment: I have the bounded object kept outside, what Can I do now to Update the controls with the old values ? I don't want to start do that like this : "textbox1.text =..." ,
Can I just change the datasource and do somehow Refresh to the screen\Controls ?

Comment: For the binding source to update the text box when you change the property, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on the objects in the BindingSource's data source. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged).